# api response is 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'

Tags: image, base64, octet-stream

i'm developing image url uploading function.
like getting image url(like copy image url from google, etc) by input tag
and send this url to server by api(because of cors issue)
and then server just fetching that url and get the response and pass to frontend.

but some images(not all) have a problem.
when fe gets a response and then convert it to blob(with blob())
and then convert to base64(with blob data). this is our flow.
but as i said, some images just return like
`data:application/octet-stream;base64,`
this.
when i print out server api' response of some images, i just get 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' this.

so the image uploading got error too.

so i want to solve this problem..

is this about like frontend problem? and have a solution ??.